# What is the ideal aspect ratio for product images?

Tags: e-commerce, search-results, listview, product, results-per-page

I need to fit in about 8 Product icons on a single screen on a product listing page, What is the ideal aspect ratio for product images? The product are from apparel industry. Also how many Items should be there in a row (3 or 4) ?

Comment: 1.61803398875 :)

Comment: Any rationale behind that ? apart from it being golden ratio.

Comment: Do these products need to be displayed with equal weighting?

Comment: Yes, In a sense they belong to same collection

Comment: Sounds like you'd have some asymmetry if you went with 3, right?  Unless you did a carousel? (which it doesn't sound like you want)

Comment: Product Listing page on an e-commerce website

Comment: Example    https://www.ae.com/men-tops/web/s-cat/10025?icid=AE:MHP:sec1:Collection:ShopTops&cm=sIN-cINR

Comment: What kind of items should be in rows?

Comment: Apparel... like shirts and pants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you respect the grid you have on the page. You can make the images fit into their containers.

For mobile, you can use a column (with a 100% width image) on the row, for tablet two, for medium screens, four and six for extra large screens. This is just an example, I'm sure you already have a grid you use.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no such thing as ideal aspect ratio of images.**

Users don't judge your products based on their image aspect ratio. The contents of the image are much more important. Product images should show comprehensive detail of the products, in order to be effective.

The image aspect ratio should comply with the template and the look and feel of your website/app. Your interface should support different image aspect ratios.

Comment: I agree that that is not an universal standard, but advice can help.

Comment: The advice is to stick to the website/app template and add support for various image aspect ratios. Edited the post.

Comment: I am creating the template :) although thanks for the advice.